# Solutions or Hints to Solve a Complex Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I came across this problem in the practice of an old book. I looked into it, and find with surprise that it's really hard.

This problem is in a Complex Analysis book, and it definitely uses some technique of complex integral. My tentative idea is to split it into partial fractions, and apply the residue thm to each part; however, partial fraction is really hard here... I guess there must be some fast way to do it.

$$
I = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2m}}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}(a_j^{2m_j}+x^{2m_j})}dx.
$$
where
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} 2m_j > 2m + 2 $$.

Comment: Hint: consider the sum of residues. Now, this does depend on a bit on your coefficients $a_j^{2m_j}.$ What properties to they satisfy?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! I'm afraid what's written above is all I've got... Considering the sum of residues is applicable to a wide range of problems; could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You have quadratic factors, and this is very important. Can you show that the residues of quadratic factors cancel out pairwise, so your sum is zero?